# An error occurred while the software was calculating the maximum value

Tags: maximize

```
In[15]:= 
Maximize[{(2 x + y)/(6 + 6 x y), 
   4 x^2 + y^2 + x y == 1, {x, y} > 0}, {x, y}] // FullSimplify

Out[15]= {Sqrt[5/2]/9, {x -> 1/Sqrt[10], y -> Sqrt[2/5]}}
```

The correct answer should be `Sqrt[2]/8`

the step is here:

[image]

Comment: There is only  `1/1000` difference between `Sqrt[5/2]/9` and `Sqrt[2]/8` numerically.  Where did your result come from?  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkaC9.png)

Comment: @Nasser I added the calculation process in the post

Comment: check your 3rd step in your hand calculation. it is wrong, it should be $(2 x+y)^2=1+3 xy$

Comment: @Nasser It has been corrected

Comment: Mathematica also functions as a typewriter. Do not hand write material that is easily typed.

Comment: `Sqrt[2]/8` is wrong.  Since `t=2/t` can not hold, `1/(2(t+2/t)`  < `Sqrt[2]/8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

FunctionRange[{(2 x + y)/(6 + 6 x y), 
  4 x^2 + y^2 + x y == 1, {x, y} > 0}, {x, y}, z]

(* 1/6 < z <= Sqrt[5/2]/9 *)

{max, arg} = 
 Maximize[{(2 x + y)/(6 + 6 x y), 
    4 x^2 + y^2 + x y == 1, {x, y} > 0}, {x, y}] // FullSimplify

(* {Sqrt[5/2]/9, {x -> 1/Sqrt[10], y -> Sqrt[2/5]}} *)

sol = Solve[{4 x^2 + y^2 + x y == 1, x > 0, y > 0}, y]

(* {{y -> ConditionalExpression[-(x/2) + 1/2 Sqrt[4 - 15 x^2], 
    0 < x < 1/2]}} *)

Maximize[{(2 x + y)/(6 + 6 x y) /. sol[[1]], 0 < x < 1/2}, 
  x] // Simplify

(* {Sqrt[5/2]/9, {x -> 1/Sqrt[10]}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

`1/(2 (t + 2/t))` can not attain it's maximum since `t==2/t` does not hold.

```
Reduce[{1/(2 (t + 2/t)) == Sqrt[2]/8, t > 0}, t, Reals]
```

> `t == Sqrt[2]`.

But if `t==Sqrt[2]` and `t==2x+y==Sqrt[1+3x*y]`, then there are not reals `{x,y}` satisfied the restrictions.

```
Reduce[{2 x + y == Sqrt[1 + 3 x*y] == Sqrt[2]}, Reals]
```

> `False`.

It means that `Sqrt[2]/8` is not the maximum. The result of Mathematica is right.